# Unexpected result when using transform.resize API

Tags: python, scripting, mesh

I have a script that works fine on a non-mirrored mesh but produces a different result on a mirrored mesh.  The script emulates the keystroke combination of "s", "x/y/z", "0" using the following line:

```
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0, 1, 1), constraint_axis=(True, False, False), 
    constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', 
    proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
```

(substituting the appropriate values for x/y/z)

When I run this on a normal mesh in wire/solid mode I get the expected results:

[image]

With a mirrored mesh in wired mode I also get the correct result.  However with mirrored and in solid mode I get this:

[image]

Moving any/all of the vertices immediately redraws the mesh and everything snaps to the correct place.  I have tried changing the "mirror" attribute to "True" and get the same results.  Is there a refresh/redraw option that I'm missing?  I'm sure there is something I'm not getting but I can't seem to find it.

Thanks for any help…

- @lan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the operator seems to actually do what it is supposed to do, but the view lags behind.

Try the following call after `transform.resize()`:

```
bpy.context.object.data.update()
```

That should trigger the update. I believe this update is incorrectly missing in the C-operator.

Comment: This fixed the issue.  Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: You're welcome! Reported to tracker: https://developer.blender.org/T38525

Comment: Brecht fixed it in trunk! [rBf49e89fa378c](https://developer.blender.org/rBf49e89fa378cde3bae9020985ed6e55724ae1ae1)